# CDI: bean-discovery-mode=annotated is ignored

Tags: java, osgi, cdi, apache-felix, weld

I use weld as CDI container. Besides I use osgi (felix). So it's javase + felix+weld+pax. I have the following beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>
```

And I have two classes:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class A {
  @Inject
  private B b;
  public void postCreate(@Observes ContainerInitialized event, BundleContext ctx) {
   b.test();
  }
}
```

And class B

```
public class B{
  public void test(){
  System.out.println("test is here");
  }
}
```

As you see class B doesn't have any @scopes or @dependent annotations. However when I start application object of class B is injected to object A and method test is invoked. Why? As I understand it mustn't be injected.

**EDIT 1**
I tried to use 1.1 version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="annotated" version="1.1">
</beans>
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: Are you using the 1.x version of weld which implements CDI 1.0?

Comment: @Sebastian S I am using version 2.2.10 which implements CDI 1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote about this to weld mailing list and this is what Jozef Hartinger (one of the main weld developers) wrote

> It seems that Pax CDI only implements explicit bean archives so far. I filed an issue at https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXCDI-186
>   You'll need to mark classes/packages you do not want discovered with
>   @Vetoed or use an exclude filter
>   http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#exclude_filters

Answer (score 0):

You must specify 1.1 version in beans.xml.

```
version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="annotated"
```

Now your bean deployment archive is explicit archive for weld.
See details: [enter link description here](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest-2.2/en-US/html/ee.html#packaging-and-deployment)

Comment: Yes. And CDI works with it as when I set bean-discovery-mode="annotated2" it throws exception.